# CSS border on image thumbnails affects all images on page

Tags: css, image, border, lightbox2

So I am creating a gallery using Lightbox2. I put all the images in "div class="container" then `enter code here`I used CSS to add a border around the thumbnail of the photo. I gave it properties for static and when hovered over.

Here's the HTML I used to set up Lightbox2:

```
<a href="images/work/cardrawing.jpg" data-lightbox="drawing" title="subaru drawing"><img src="images/work/thumbnails/cardrawing_thumb.jpg" /></a>
```

It worked fine. I then added the following code to the bottom of the "lightbox.css" file to give it specific properties:

```
a img{border:5px solid #cccccc;} a:hover img{border:5px solid #0b6f8a;}
```

This also worked great, however, it affected all other images on my site that have an anchored link or anything. Almost every image in general. Whats the best way to categorize everything as to only affect certain images?

Comment: The best way to affect specific images is to assign an `id` to that image, then target that particular `id` in your CSS. Or if you have a group of images that should all have the same CSS, assign them each the same `class`

Comment: @DrydenLong That is not the best way; That would require each image to have an ID, and there to be a long list of selectors in CSS.

Comment: @popnoodles I agree, my comment was meant to inform OP about styling a single image. I then added that he should use classes to style groups of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ID's or classes. Have specific `img` tags set up so it's like:

```
<a href="images/work/cardrawing.jpg" data-lightbox="drawing" title="subaru drawing">
    <img class="hoverImage" src="images/work/thumbnails/cardrawing_thumb.jpg" />
</a>
```

and then in your CSS you can use:

```
a img.hoverImage{
    border:5px solid #cccccc;
} 
a img.hoverImage:hover{
    border:5px solid #0b6f8a;
}
```

You can then set specific properties/hovers for each image if necessary.

Comment: `a img .hoverImage` will never target anything

Comment: This did not work. Now nothing happens to any picture. I created a class `.gallery` and and applied it to my image:

`<a href="images/work/cardrawing.jpg" data-lightbox="drawing" title="subaru drawing"><img class="gallery" src="images/work/thumbnails/cardrawing_thumb.jpg" /></a>`

I then edited my CSS to match so:

`a img .gallery{
    border:5px solid #cccccc;
} 
a:hover img .gallery{
    border:5px solid #0b6f8a;
}`

Did I do this wrong or what?

Comment: Sorry, the `:hover` was implemented wrong. I fixed the code above.

Comment: What do you mean implemented wrong? Do I have it in the wrong place in my code?

Comment: Here's a basic [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2E7P/3/) of the code. Change the `a img .gallery` to `a img.gallery`, and `a:hover img .gallery` to `a img.gallery:hover`

Comment: Simple spaces make for a frustrating morning. That did the trick though! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more specific with your CSS. Your images have the class lightbox.

```
<a...><img class="lighbox" ... /></a>
```

so you would use

```
a img.lighbox{...}
```

and

```
a img.lighbox:hover{...}
```

Comment: Should change lighbox typo to lightbox to be consistent with description

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the images by class

Html:

```
<a href="images/work/cardrawing.jpg" data-lightbox="drawing" title="subaru drawing">
    <img class="lightbox" src="images/work/thumbnails/cardrawing_thumb.jpg" />
</a>
```

CSS:

```
img.lightbox { 
    border:5px solid #cccccc; 
} 

a img.lightbox:hover { 
    border:5px solid #0b6f8a; 
}
```

Comment: In this case because you are setting up an image gallery you wouldn't use IDs to target the images because IDs are specific to one single html element. It's technically possible to do but you'd need to reference each specific img ID in your CSS which would make it unnecessarily long.

Using a class you can target all the gallery images with one class, and need only reference them once in your CSS.